# Font size randomly getting small C# control with windows CE device | .Net 3.5 Compact framework

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

In my C# application. Button or any List view control font size getting randomly small in run time.For more information please find attached snap

Note : This is happening in device only

I have used .net 3.5 Compact framework with windows CE device [image]

Can any have a experience in same issue?

Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here and for your other question you may need to contact BeeMobile about there custom contols.

Comment: @Josef2 : Thank for replay but my question is like if i am not using BeeMobile control then what is solution. My first concern is to use Windows CE control

Comment: Imagine you're someone that wants to answer your question - what information do you think they would need?

Comment: Thios is not the first time a custom control looses it's font settings. In general, when you ask the OS for a font you might get what you want, but best is to use a font resource provided with the app and use that explicitly.